# What are the different TYPEs that could be output from lsblk?

Tags: bash, partitioning

Executing `lsblk -lno TYPE $DEVICE`, I have seen TYPEs like *disk*, *crypto*, *part*, *linux_raid_member*, *loop*, and possibly others. I am writing a Bash script that needs to interpret this value. I have checked the `man` page for `lsblk`, but I couldn't find a list of possible TYPEs in there. What are all the possible values?

Comment: A dvd drive is type `rom`... I'm not sure where to look in sysfs & udev db to find all the types, but should be in them somewhere. Source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [the lsblk implementation](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/misc-utils/lsblk.c#L402-L456), it can be:

- Lines 406-407 (device is partition) - 'part'
- Lines 409-433 (device is device mapper - dm) - 'lvm', 'crypt', 'dmraid', 'mpath', 'path', 'dm' (listed on line 413)
- Lines 433-435 (device is loop device) - 'loop'
- Lines 436-442 (device is multiple devices - md (raid)) - 'md', 'linear', 'raid0', 'raid1', 'raid4', 'raid5', 'raid10', 'multipath' (additional info about md levels from https://linux.die.net/man/4/md)
- Lines 442-451 (otherwise - scsi devices) - 'disk', 'tape', 'printer', 'processor', 'worm', 'rom', 'scanner', 'mo-disk', 'changer', 'comm', 'raid', 'enclosure', 'rbc', 'osd', 'no-lun' (additional info from https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/lib/blkdev.c#L325-L362)

So all possible options are:
`part`, `lvm`, `crypt`, `dmraid`, `mpath`, `path`, `dm`, `loop`, `md`, `linear`, `raid0`, `raid1`, `raid4`, `raid5`, `raid10`, `multipath`, `disk`, `tape`, `printer`, `processor`, `worm`, `rom`, `scanner`, `mo-disk`, `changer`, `comm`, `raid`, `enclosure`, `rbc`, `osd`, and `no-lun`

You mentioned you have seen `crypto` – that was probably `crypt` and not `crypto`.

You also mentioned `linux_raid_member` – this is a filesystem type (different column of lsblk) as can be seen from examples here: http://www.fibrevillage.com/storage/53-lsblk-command-examples

Comment: Thank you for this! Yes, I probably mistook crypt for crypto. Also, yeah, I definitely read linux_raid_member in the FSTYPE column, not TYPE! I have been looking for this information for so long, but had no idea where to find it. Thanks again!